# Exibir 2 dados no visualg com estrutura de repetição

Tags: visualg

Estou tentado exibir 2 nomes com, Para e faça, se eu colocar o escreval dentro do laço ele vai ler e escrever ai fica bagunçado, como faria para ler os 2 depois escrever?

```
Algoritmo "semnome"
Var
i,:inteiro
nome:caractere


Inicio
para i de 1 ate 2 faca
escreval("Digite o nome: ")
leia(nome)

fimpara
escreval("Nome: ",cont)

Fimalgoritmo
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Não conheço muito de Visualg, mas vamos pela logica:

Para você ler e armazenar vários valores é necessário que você tenha variáveis para dedicar espaço de memoria para isso. Ao invés de criar varias variáveis (nome1,nome2,nome3) você pode criar um vetor:

```
vet: nomes [1..10] de caractere //1..10 é o inicio e fim do seu vetor.
```

Assim é só ir adicionando nomes nessa "lista" de nomes atráves de um `PARA` e depois dar outro laço de repetição para percorrer este vetor.

```
Algoritmo "semnome" 
Var i,:inteiro 
vet: nomes [1..2] de caractere //1..2 é o inicio e fim do seu vetor.

Inicio 
  para i de 1 ate 2 faca 
    escreval("Digite o nome: ") 
    leia(nomes[i])
  fimpara 

//Inicio de outro PARA para escrever os nomes.
  para i de 1 ate 2 faca 
    escreval("Nome: ",nomes[i])
  fimpara
```

Como eu disse, meu conhecimento de visualg não é lá aquelas coisas mas acredito que ajude :D

Comment: é isso msm valeu :D